# sending https request using inetc

Tags: download, nsis

So I tried to send some POST data to an url using this code:

```
StrCpy $PostStr "a=input1&c=input2"
inetc::post $PostStr "https://url/index.php" "$INSTDIR\result.html" /END

Pop $0
StrCmpS $0 "OK" success failedToSubmit
failedToSubmit:
  MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "There was an error submitting information: $0"
Abort

success:
  MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION "Your information was successfully received"
```

but when the url is in https, the following message always appeared:

```
There was an error submitting information: SendRequest Error
```

I tried this with http, and it run smoothly. The server php script does nothing but echo the POST variable.

Have I missed something in dealing with the https with inetc?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a self signed cert? Does Internet Explorer give any warnings when visiting the site?

Comment: yes, it is self signed. I forgot about that :p is there any way to add the cert to the exception list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INetC should be using the `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA + SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION` flags on https URLs and there seems to be some kind of auth retry code in there so I'm not sure why it is not working.

There are other flags like `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID` that it is not using, maybe you could request a new /nosecurity switch [here](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?threadid=198596)...

Comment: I had a similar issue so for those that come here with the same or similar problem:  It's also worth checking that in the case where the server you are accessing is using TLS 1.x, then check: Internet Options > Advanced Tab > [Scroll settings to bottom] > at least one of the "Use TLS 1.x" options should be checked - which it just might not be, depending on a variety of things such as what OS or version of IE you have, or what version of McAfee might have previously been present. It's an easy check. More on [TLS & web browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers)