# NSIS inetc - HTTPS gives SendRequest Error

Tags: https, installation, nsis

I am using inetc plugin of NSIS. And I am trying to call one URL which uses HTTPS protocol. The URL gives me SendRequest error.

As posted [this seems to be solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467843/sending-https-request-using-inetc)
But I'm unsure how to set the flags as told by @Anders

Anyone has any pointers regarding this?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
- Ganesh

Comment: Can Internet Explorer download the file without errors? Is the certificate self-signed/expired etc?

Comment: It gives certificate error. After clicking continue I can access the file.
FYI I'm sending plaintext in the response from the server

Comment: I got this error because my DNS server was horribly misconfigured, so I second Anders' idea of checking IE.

Answer (score 1):

INetC uses the `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA` and `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION` WinINet flags but it does not use `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID` nor `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID`. Like I suggested in the other answer, you should ask the author of this plugin to add a /nosecurity flag if you believe you need these flags or just use plain HTTP.