# How to request plain HTTP from a website using Inetc

Tags: nsis

Haya, at the moment im trying to solve a problem in my code regarding a `SendRequest error` since i believe the website im using (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt) is not being validated as having a correct certificate by inetc or something close to this - i read here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26893754/11718125) that to fix this i could use plain http.

how could i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you linked to is old, INetC now supports a `/WEAKSECURITY` switch.

To use plain HTTP, just change the `https:` part in the URL to `http:`. This does not work everywhere, some servers might force a redirect to HTTPS.

This works for me:

```
Section
InitPluginsDir
inetc::get /WEAKSECURITY /SILENT "https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt" "$PluginsDir\License.txt" /END
ClearErrors
FileOpen $1 "$PluginsDir\License.txt" r
IfErrors 0 +2
Abort "No file?"
loop:
    FileRead $1 $2
    IfErrors +3
    DetailPrint $2
    Goto loop
FileClose $1
SectionEnd
```

Comment: ah thanks again for the quick response anders! - this works perfectly!